# How to use operator= with anonymous objects in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, operator-overloading

I have a class with an overloaded operator:

```
IPAddress& IPAddress::operator=(IPAddress &other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        delete data;
        this->init(other.getVersion());
        other.toArray(this->data);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

When I try to compile this:

```
IPAddress x;
x = IPAddress(IPV4, "192.168.2.10");
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:43:39: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘x = IPAddress(4, ((const std::string&)(& std::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"192.168.2.10"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))))’
IPAddress.h:28:20: note: candidate is: IPAddress& IPAddress::operator=(IPAddress&)
```

However, these two work fine (though they don't serve me any purpose):

```
IPAddress x;
IPAddress(IPV4, "192.168.2.10") = x;
```

-

```
IPAddress x;
x = *(new IPAddress(IPV4, "192.168.2.10"));
```

What's going on? Am I assuming something incorrect about the way the assignment operator works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right side of the assignment operator should take a `const IPAddress&`.

Temporary objects can be bound to const references, but not to non-const references. This is why `x = IPAddress(IPV4, "192.168.2.10");` doesn't work.

`IPAddress(IPV4, "192.168.2.10") = x;` works because it is legal to invoke member functions on temporary objects.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just had to change a few other methods called by operator= to be const.

Answer (score 4):

The assignment operator is defined using `const`:

```
IPAddress& IPAddress::operator=(const IPAddress &other)
```

Your temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference, as it is theoretically destructed before the call to the assignment operator (this might not happen due to optimization, don't rely on it).