# Operator Overloading Errors "no match for operator error"

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am getting no match for 'operator +' error in main section.
I overloaded all of the operators as friend except =
I tried to debug but could not figured it out
I don't know, what I am skipping.
Please advise.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
long num;
long den;
public:
fraction( ){num = 0L ; den = 1L ;}
fraction(long l_num,long l_den){num = l_num ; den = l_den ;}
fraction(const fraction& f){num=f.num; den=f.den;}
~fraction ( ){}
long getNum (void) const{return num ;}
long getDen (void) const{return den ;}
void  print(void)
{
 if(den==0)den=1L;
 cout<<num<<"/"<<den <<endl;
}
fraction  inc ( )
{
 long numX = (num) + (den);
 long denY = (den);
 return fraction(numX, denY );
}
friend fraction operator +(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);
friend fraction operator +(int i, fraction &f2);
friend fraction &operator++(fraction & f1);
fraction operator =( const fraction &f);
friend fraction operator -(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);
friend fraction operator *(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);
friend fraction operator /(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);
};
inline fraction operator +(fraction &f1, fraction &f2)
{
fraction temp;
temp.num=(f1.num*f2.den)+(f1.den*f2.num);
temp.den=f1.den*f2.den;
return temp;
}
inline fraction operator +(int i, fraction &f2)
{
fraction temp;
temp.num=i*f2.den+f2.num;
temp.den=f2.den;
return temp;
}
inline fraction &operator++(fraction& f1)
{
f1.num=f1.num+f1.den;
return f1;
}
inline fraction fraction::operator=(const fraction &f)
{
num=f.num;
den=f.den;
return*this;
}
inline fraction operator -(fraction &f1, fraction &f2)
{
fraction temp;
temp.num=(f1.num*f2.den)-(f1.den*f2.num);
temp.den=f1.den*f2.den;
return temp;
}
inline fraction operator *(fraction &f1, fraction &f2)
{
fraction temp;
temp.num=f1.num*f2.num;
temp.den=f1.den*f2.den;
return temp;
}
inline fraction operator /(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2)
{
fraction temp;
temp.num=f1.num*f2.den;
temp.den=f1.den*f2.num;
return temp;
}
int main ( )
{
fraction f1, f2(2L,0L);
fraction f3(f2);
f1.print();
f2.print();
f3.print();
f3 = f3 + fraction (-5 , 4);
f1 = f2 + f3;
f1.print ( );
f1 = f2 - f3;
f1.print();
f1 = f2 * f3;
f1.print();
(++ (++f1)).print();
f1 = f2 / f3;
f1.print();
f1 = 5 + f1;
f1.print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation please

Answer (score 0):

All of your operators take their parameters as references to non-const `fraction`. Which means they can only be called with non-const *lvalues* of type `fraction`. A temporary (such as the result of `fraction(-5, 4)`) is an *rvalue*, not an *lvalue*, and thus cannot be used as an argument to your operators.

I dare say it's *wrong* for arithmetic operators to take non-const references as parameters: that indicates they will modify their operands, which is plain wrong. You should change all the binary operators' parameters from `fraction &` to `const fraction &`.

A reference to `const` allows rvalues to bind it to, so your code will work as expected.

Of course, this doesn't apply to `operator++` (that's why I mention *binary* operators above). `++` actually modifies its operand, so in its case, a reference to non-const is the correct approach. The same would apply to compound assignment operators such as `+=`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to do that. Thank you very much for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing all the errors

```
f3 = f3 + fraction (-5 , 4)
```

You are using `fraction operator +(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);` function to add an object and an anonymous object.

But anonymous object are only temporary. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265254/how-to-use-operator-with-anonymous-objects-in-c) answer.

Remove that line and your code should work.

Edit:

Might work if you change

`fraction operator +(fraction &f1 , fraction &f2);`

to

`fraction operator +(fraction &f1 , fraction f2);`

Comment: That's treating the symptom instead of the disease.

Comment: I meant remove that and create another object and then pass it for addition.

Comment: Same problem. Whys should arithmetic operators require lvalues in the first place?